# Sum of inverse chi squared random variables

Tags: probability-distributions, random-variables

Let $X$ and $Y$ be two i.i.d. random variables that follow an inverse chi squared distribution. Let $\nu$ be the corresponding degrees of freedom parameter.

What is the distribution of the sum $S=X+Y$ ?

**Update**:
Here we use the following definition:

$$\text{PDF}= \frac{1}{\Gamma(\nu /2)}2^{-\nu/2 }x^{-\nu/2-1} e^{-1/(2x)}$$

Comment: Can you start by providing the definition (functional form) for your inverse chi-squared distribution. There are multiple competing definitions in the literature.

Comment: @wolfies Question updated. Thank you for your comment!